# Interrupted installation of Ubuntu leads to endless restarting

Tags: installation

I was installing Ubuntu 12.04(?) Lts and I didn't notice that my battery was running out because I fell asleep while waiting for the installation. When I tried to restart the pc after recharging, I tried to reinstall it. When the cd is attached my pc restarted after sometime. When I remove the cd it leads to the grub rescue.

By the way I'm new in using Ubuntu so I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: Just reinstall on the same drives. Select exactly same options and it works.

Comment: Uhm. When I open my pc (without the installation cd) it leads to grub rescue. When I open it with the installation cd, the pc restarts on its own

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the installation from the start. Probably the installation got half finished and didn't complete. Also, remember to leave your portable devices connected to AC always that you are installing something big, like an OS.